# showing $\psi: R\to \mathbb C$ is ring isomorphism.

Tags: ring-theory

Below is an example from I.N. Herstein:

> Let  $R=\Bigg\{\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
> a & b \\
> -b & a \end{array} \right)\Bigg|a,b\in \mathbb R\Bigg\}$ and let $\mathbb C$ be the field of complex numbers. Define $\psi :R\to \mathbb C$ by $\psi\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
> a & b \\
> -b & a \end{array} \right)=a+bi.$

It is asked to prove that $\psi$ is a ring isomorphism of $R$ onto $\mathbb C$ .

can anyone help me with some hint how to prove the ring isomorphism.

Comment: First show it's a homomorphism, then show it's bijective. Where are you having trouble?

Comment: By restricting $R$ via the projection $r \rightarrow (1\quad 0) r$, $\psi$ simply becomes the natural isomorphism from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb C$.

Comment: @kittuu Please note the discussion under Sami Ben Romdhane's answer below. You should probably indicate what kind of isomorphism you want: one of rings, of vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$, or of $\mathbb{R}$-algebras.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prove that

- $\psi$ is a morphism of rings i.e.

$$\psi( M_z+M_{z'})= \psi(M_z)+\psi(M_{z'})$$
and
$$\psi(M_zM_{z'})=\psi(M_z)\psi(M_{z'})$$
and
$$\psi(M_1)=1$$
where
$$ z=a+ib\quad;\quad M_z=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
-b & a \end{pmatrix} $$

- $\psi$ is injective i.e. $\ker \psi=\{M_0\}$
- $\psi$ is surjective i.e. $\operatorname{Im}\psi=\Bbb C$.

Comment: What the introduction of a scalar and mention of a linear transformation? Not really necessary to prove $\psi$ is a ring isomorphism.

Comment: One should also check that multiplication is preserved !

Comment: Yes you're right I didn't see the ring-theory tag and my answer is for the isomorphism of vector spaces.

Comment: @manthanomen True, but the OP didn't clearly state that he wants a ring isomorphism. Maybe he wants an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra isomorphism, in which case one indeed needs to check that $\psi$ preserves multiplication by elements of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @DanShved My question deals with ring-isomorphism..

Comment: @kittuu It would be a good idea to edit your question and add this information, to make it easier to read for future visitors.

Comment: Just calculate and you will find the result.@kittuu